# Go convert interface{} to map

Tags: go

I'm convert interface{} to map[string]string.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    data := `{"1":"2", "3": "4"}`
    var v interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &v)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", v)
    _, ok := v.(map[string]interface{})
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", ok)
    _, ok = v.(map[string]string)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", ok)
    _, ok = v.(map[interface{}]interface{})
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", ok)
}
```

The code is here https://play.golang.org/p/I_clyMdaGzw

why map[string]interface{} is ok，but map[string]string, map[interface{}]interface{} not works?

Comment: `map[string]interface{}`, `map[string]string`, and `map[interface{}]interface{}` are distinct and different types.

Comment: You are not converting anything here. Those are [type *assertions*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions), and v simply doesn't have one of latter two types.

Answer (score 4):

Unmarshalling a `json` object to a `map` or `interface` will always use `map[string]interface{}` to Unmarshal a JSON object (as beiping96 noted in his answer).

Use `reflect.TypeOf` to see what type a variable holds. You can only **cast** it to that type. If you want another type you need to **convert** it.

Here an example to get to `map[string]string`:

```golang
func main() {
    data := `{"1":"2", "3": "4"}`
    var v interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &v); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var res = map[string]string{}
    for k, v := range v.(map[string]interface{}) {
        res[k] = v.(string)
    }
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(res), res)
}
```

Note: that I am assuming the structure is known and I'm not checking for types. This will panic if the types are not as assumed. Use the `val, ok := ...` pattern you used to prevent panics.

The above is however not the idiomatic way to UnMarshal to `map[string]string`. The usual way (if you know the structure of the JSON string) would be to let the `json` package deal with the type casting:

```golang
func main() {
    data := `{"1":"2", "3": "4"}`
    var res map[string]string
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &res); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(res), res)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Unmarshal

```
To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of these in the interface value:

bool, for JSON booleans
float64, for JSON numbers
string, for JSON strings
[]interface{}, for JSON arrays
map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
nil for JSON null
```

because used `interface{}` for decode, the default type of json objects is `map[string]interface{}`